Azure function timeout only after deployment
I'm working on a .NET 8 Azure Function; when I run it in development (localhost), it runs fine, but when I deploy from Visual Studio. I get this error

500 - The request timed out.
The web server failed to respond within the specified time

I'm using SQL Server. I thought it may be a IP whitelisting issue but when I put a breakpoint in the Program.cs file, it doesn't even break.
Here is the Function that I'm running
namespace GenPDF {
    public class GenPDF
    {
        private readonly IDropBoxService _dropBox;

        public GenPDF(IDropBoxService dropBox)
        {
            _dropBox = dropBox;
        }

        [Function("PDFGen")]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get",Route = "PDFGen/{state}/{type}/{id}")] HttpRequest req, string state,string type,string id
           )
        {
                
            QuestPDF.Settings.License = LicenseType.Community;
            return new StatusCodeResult(200);
           

        }
    } 

}

You're getting a 500, that's an error in your code. Do you have logging to show you the errors?

@my coding  Can you share the function code which you have tried?

@Pavan I Added the function code

@mycoding  Can you check the below solution.

I have created the http trigger function with runtime stack .NET 8.0 and added above code in function code.

The consumption plan default timeout is 5 minutes, and it can be extended to a maximum of 10 minutes.
The Premium plan timeout can be configured to be much longer or even infinite. Check once with premium plan of function app.
The below function executed successfully in local.

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace GenPDF
{
    public class GenPDF
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GenPDF> _logger;

        public GenPDF(ILogger<GenPDF> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("PDFGen")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "PDFGen/{state}/{type}/{id}")] HttpRequestData req,
                                                 string state, string type, string id,
                                                 FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("PDFGen function triggered with state: {state}, type: {type}, id: {id}");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteStringAsync("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}


By Configure the application insights in program.cs to monitor logs in application insights. check below:

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var settings = config.Build();
                ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions options = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
                {
                    InstrumentationKey = settings["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]
                };
                config.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options);
            })
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
            .Build();

        host.Run();

Output:



I have created the function app with premium app service plan in azure portal. I have deployed function into azure portal successfully. check below:



The function ran successfully in portal as well. check below:

Check the Application Insights logs for any exceptions or errors that might give more insight into why the function is timing out.
Monitor the logs in application insights.

